# My first click on a jquery mobile page adds overflow:hidden on body tag

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm still relatively new to JQM and just attempted to upgrade to 1.3.2.
I'm aware that JQM loads subsequent page request into the DOM and then transitions over while keeping the first page as part of the DOM.

What I'm noticing in 1.3.2 is that on any subsequent page request my first click on the page adds the classes `ui-mobile-viewport-transitioning viewport-fade` to my body tag.  As part of the `ui-mobile-viewport-transitioning` class comes an `overflow:hidden` property effectively preventing the user from scrolling further down the page.

I know I can just add a custom CSS rule along the lines of:

```
body.ui-mobile-viewport{
    overflow:visible;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

Or potentially use rel="external" for all of my links, but I have questions.

1. What is the purpose of this as a default feature?  I can understand sometimes you may want this type of functionality, but I can't see it as the defacto for all of your pages.
2. Is there effectively some JQM event I can listen for and set an option to prevent this from happening?

**EDIT*:** The above CSS styles do not in fact correct the issue.
Instead this seems to work:

```
body.ui-mobile-viewport .ui-page{
    height:99.9%;
    overflow:visible;
}
```

Instead of using `!important` I just made sure this css class was after the JQM css stylesheet.  If this is not possible then you may have to use `!important`.

I've gotten around this issue, but am sure this is not the proper way to prevent it.  I'm still curious if there is a way to prevent it which is already built into JQM.

Comment: Did you find the "correct" way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Add `data-tap-toggle="false"` to your footer. This will prevent the tap/toggle => https://forum.jquery.com/topic/ui-fixed-hidden-on-click-event-1-1-rc2

Comment: Thank you @Floern , I unfortunately do not have access to this code anymore to test this on.